# TypeError trying to use @mock.patch

Tags: python, facebook, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to test a method that uses the Facebook SDK. My test looks like this (inside of a class that inherits from unittest.TestCase):

```
@mock.patch.multiple(engine.facebook.GraphAPI,
                     request=TEST_ME,
                     extend_access_token=TEST_AUTH_TOKEN)
@mock.patch.object(service.models.Person, "save")
def setUp(self, mock_save, mock_request, mock_extend_access_token):
    ...
```

When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
TypeError: setUp() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

I'm confused because [as far as I can tell, my code is the same as the example in the documentation](http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/patch.html#nesting-patch-decorators). I'm using Python 2.7 with the Mock library. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't it be def setUp(self, mock_save, request, extend_access_token)?

Comment: I thought that the names were arbitrary and determined by position? But I'm new to the mock library so I could be wrong. Feel free to post an answer correcting me, I'll vote it up.

Comment: Mock is sometimes tricky. Did it work?

Comment: @RafaelBarros Nope. I've restructured the test a little bit (removed the second patch.object) but it still looks like arguments from patch.multiple aren't going through -- it now complains that it wants 3 arguments and got 1.

Comment: I ended up writing it to avoid using `patch.multiple` and the test is working fine now, but it would still be nice to understand where I went wrong the first time.

Comment: ah, yes, another attempt could be removing the request=TEST_ME on the signature of patch.multiple, and attributing it inside the setUp function.
like this:

@mock.patch.multiple(engine.facebook.GraphAPI, request, extend_access_token)
@mock.patch.object(service.models.Person, "save")
def setUp(self, mock_save, mock_request, mock_extend_access_token): ...